# How can I load color calibration from command line (what put it into scheduler on logon)?

Tags: windows-7, color-profiles

I have such problem I have SpyderExpress and Radeon Video Card and **after any hibernation Windows 7 does not load color profile for monitor**.

I read tenths of answers and tutorials and try many methods but it not works.

Every time I need to do 'Screen Resoluton' -> 'Advanced settings' -> 'Color management' -> 'ICC Profiles' (select default profile) -> 'Set as default profile'. It is very stupid task which irritate.

Default color profile is not loaded by default as should be. It only load after manual action every day :)

Since it is not working I want to force loading from command line - it is faster than more than 7 clicks. How can I load color profile for each display I have two monitors.

Comment: Have you tried [Argyl CMS](http://www.argyllcms.com/)? I tried it today and it's working for me. After installation (which is painful) just run `dispwin profilelocation.icm`. I haven't tried with multiple monitors though, I expect there are options for that.